# how to find the minimum from a divide of two column in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to find the minimum division of two columns, only with values in a third column from a list. 
My dataframe is:

```
   ID  size  price
0   1     5    300
1   2    10    500
2   3    20    600
3   4    35    800
4   5    65    900
5   6    70   1000
```

I want to find the minimum price/size, only from ids with value in list.

```
ids_wanted = [1,4,6]
```

I did this code, and it works, but I feel it is costly and unnecessary to make a new dataframe for the task.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
index = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
i = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6], index=index)
s = pd.Series([5,10,20,35,65,70],index= index)
p = pd.Series([300,500,600,800,900,1000],index= index)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[i,s,p],columns = ["ID","size","price"])
print("original df:\n",df,"\n")

ids_wanted = [1,4,6]
df_with_ids_wanted = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(ids_wanted)]
print("df with ids wanted:\n",df_with_ids_wanted,"\n")
price_per_byte = df_with_ids_wanted['price'] / df_with_ids_wanted['size']
df_with_ids_wanted_ppb = df_with_ids_wanted.assign(pricePerByte=price_per_byte)
print("df with ids wanted and price/size column:\n",df_with_ids_wanted_pps,"\n")
min_ppb = df_with_ids_wanted_pps['pricePerByte'].min()
print("min price per byte:",min_ppb)
```

outputs:

```
original df:
    ID  size  price
0   1     5    300
1   2    10    500
2   3    20    600
3   4    35    800
4   5    65    900
5   6    70   1000 

df with ids wanted:
    ID  size  price
0   1     5    300
3   4    35    800
5   6    70   1000 

df with ids wanted and price/size column:
    ID  size  price  pricePerByte
0   1     5    300     60.000000
3   4    35    800     22.857143
5   6    70   1000     14.285714 

min price per byte: 14.285714285714286
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to be concise, you can try this:

```
i = range(1,7)
s = [5,10,20,35,65,70]
p = [300,500,600,800,900,1000]
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":i,"size":s,"price":p})
df
```

Output:

```
    ID  size    price
0   1   5   300
1   2   10  500
2   3   20  600
3   4   35  800
4   5   65  900
5   6   70  1000
```

next line will look like this:

```
id_chosen = [1,4,6]
(df[df.ID.isin(id_chosen)]["price"]/df[df.ID.isin(id_chosen)]["size"]).min()
```

Output:

```
14.285714285714286
```

or

```
min_div = (df[df.ID.isin(id_chosen)]["price"]/df[df.ID.isin(id_chosen)]["size"]).min()
print("the minimum price/size is {}".format(min_div))
```

Output:

```
the minimum price/size is 14.285714285714286
```

This way, you do not have to create new dataframes.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

i'd do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dict = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'size': [5, 10, 20, 35, 65, 70],
        'price': [300, 500, 600, 800, 900, 1000]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df['price/byte'] = df['price'] / df['size']

ids_wanted = [1, 4, 6]

subset = df[df['id'].isin(ids_wanted)]

sorted_values = subset.sort_values(by='price/byte', ascending = True)

print(sorted_values['price/byte'].iloc[0])
```

Comment: I would suggest that as much as possible, Avoid for loops In pandas/NumPy if u can. Faster methods abound